# Model comes null to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller

This is my first ask. I have 2 models for 1 view. I built the code but i have a problem. data comes null from view to controller.

Models:

Mom model:

```
    public class BildirimOlusturViewModel
    {
        public BildirimOlusturModel bildirimOlusturModel { get; set; }
        public TagBoxViewModel tagBoxViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Child models:

```
    public class BildirimOlusturModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen bildirim tipi seçiniz")]
        public string BildirimTipi { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen alıcı tipi seçiniz")]
        public string AliciTipi { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen alıcı seçiniz")]
        public string Alicilar { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen bir başlık giriniz")]
        public string Baslik { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mesaj boş olamaz")]
        public string Mesaj { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TagBoxViewModel
    {
        public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
@model xyz.Web.Notifications.Models.BildirimOlusturViewModel
<form method="post" asp-controller="Bildirim" asp-action="BildirimOlustur">
...
            @(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBoxFor(s => s.bildirimOlusturModel.AliciTipi)
        .Placeholder("Alıcı Tipi...")
                    .DataSource(new List<SelectListItem> {
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = "Personel",
                                Value = "personel".ToString()
                            },
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = "Müşteri",
                                Value = "musteri".ToString()
                            }})
                     .ValueExpr("Value").DisplayExpr("Text")
                     .OnValueChanged("alicitipi_changed")
                     .ID("slcAliciTipi")
            )
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @(Html.DevExtreme().TagBoxFor(x => x.bildirimOlusturModel.Alicilar)
                .Items(Model.tagBoxViewModel.Items)
                .SearchEnabled(true)
                .Placeholder("Alıcı...")
                .ID("TagBoxAlici")
            )
            @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(x => x.bildirimOlusturModel.Baslik)
        .Placeholder("Başlık...")
            )
            <input type="text" id="Mesaj"  asp-for="bildirimOlusturModel.Mesaj" name="bildirimOlusturModel.Mesaj" id="bildirimOlusturModel.Mesaj"/>

 @(Html.DevExtreme().Button() 
        .Text("Submit")
        .Type(ButtonType.Default)
        .StylingMode(ButtonStylingMode.Contained)
        .Width(120)
        .UseSubmitBehavior(true)
            )
</form>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult BildirimOlustur(BildirimOlusturModel model)
        {
            string sAlicilar = model.Alicilar;
            string sAliciTipi = model.AliciTipi;
            string sBaslik = model.Baslik;
            string sBildirimTipi = model.BildirimTipi;
            string sMesaj = model.Mesaj;
        }
```

Submit button sends me inside the post method but not sends the model. My variables coming null. Thank you for help.

Comment: To most your model back to the controller you need to wrap your elements in Html.BeginForm.

Comment: sorry, I crop a part of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. controller was waiting for the wrong parameter.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult BildirimOlustur(BildirimOlusturViewModel model)
    {
        BildirimOlusturModel mdl = new BildirimOlusturModel();
        mdl = model.bildirimOlusturModel;
        string sAlicilar = mdl.Alicilar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [FromBody] attribute before your argument.

```
 public IActionResult BildirimOlustur([Frombody] BildirimOlusturModel model)
```